# How To Toggle Lines & Curves Names Visibility On Spotfire With Iron Python?

Tags: python, bar-chart, ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I've been trying to create an IronPython script to toggle my BarChart Horizontal Lines names with no luck.

I would like to achieve this with a button click:
[image]

The code I am currently using is:

```
from System.Drawing import Color
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

# vis parameter referencing an existing BarChart visualization
vis = vis.As[BarChart]()

# Read the document property with the toggle value (true/false)
Document.Properties['GenericToggleLineNames'] = not Document.Properties['GenericToggleLineNames']

#Loop through all the Lines & Curves collection
if Document.Properties['GenericToggleLineNames']:
    for fm in vis.FittingModels:
        if fm.Line.DisplayName == 'Defined Underload Limit':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = 'Defined Underload Limit'
        elif fm.Line.DisplayName == 'Defined Warning Limit':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = 'Defined Warning Limit'
        elif fm.Line.DisplayName == 'Defined Critical Limit':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = 'Defined Critical Limit'
else:
    for fm in vis.FittingModels:
        if fm.Line.DisplayName == 'Defined Underload Limit':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = ''
        elif fm.Line.DisplayName == 'Defined Warning Limit':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = ''
        elif fm.Line.DisplayName == 'Defined Critical Limit':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = ''
```

But, when I get to the "Show = true", the code does not change the CustomDisplayNames.

According to the Spotfire API, [DisplayName](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire-analyst/7.13.0/doc/api/html/4f1dae7b-c6cd-026c-a8a0-0ec0ea8049c2.htm) only offers a *get* method, while 
[CustomDisplayName](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire-analyst/7.11.0/TIB_sfire-analyst_7.11.0_api/html/F_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_FittingModels_ReferenceCurve_PropertyNames_CustomDisplayName.htm) offers both *get* and *set*.

Does anyone know how to create this toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working in a hideous way. Will share it here if anyone needs it, but please, would love to find a proper way to do it.

Even though [Spotfire API documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire-analyst/7.13.0/doc/api/html/4f1dae7b-c6cd-026c-a8a0-0ec0ea8049c2.htm) mentions that the 
ReferenceCurve.DisplayName is a read-only Property (only have the *get* method), it looks like it's being changed when CustomDisplayName is updated.

With that in mind, I've created another set of *IFs*, looking for the "new" DisplayName and replacing them with the old ones.

```
# Imports
from System.Drawing import Color
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

#Add a vis parameter referencing an existing LineChart visualization
vis = vis.As[BarChart]()

#Loop through all the Lines & Curves collection
Document.Properties['GenericVisualisationDescriptions'] = not Document.Properties['GenericVisualisationDescriptions']

if Document.Properties['GenericVisualisationDescriptions']:
    for fm in vis.FittingModels:
        if fm.Line.DisplayName == ' ':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = 'Defined Underload Limit'
        elif fm.Line.DisplayName == '  ':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = 'Defined Warning Limit'
        elif fm.Line.DisplayName == '   ':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = 'Defined Critical Limit'
else:
    for fm in vis.FittingModels:
        print fm.Line.DisplayName
        print fm.Line.CustomDisplayName
        if fm.Line.DisplayName == 'Defined Underload Limit':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = ' '
        elif fm.Line.DisplayName == 'Defined Warning Limit':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = '  '
        elif fm.Line.DisplayName == 'Defined Critical Limit':
            fm.Line.CustomDisplayName = '   '
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on how to do this.  Please go here -- https://datashoptalk.com/ironpython-in-spotfire-turning-lines-curves-on-and-off/.  The code will vary depending on what you have on the page.  Please upvote if you get to the right answer with this post.

Comment: Hi @JulieBMA, 
I've seen your blog post yesterday (by the way, I've been helped by many of your blog posts in the past :) ) but in this case, I would like to keep displaying the line, but only hide its title. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me what Document Property and data type you have setup.

Comment: The only Document Property that I'm using for that is GenericToggleLineNames', which is a Boolean. The vis parameter is a Visualization input.

Answer (score 0):

The annotations of the lines are are stored in the Line.Details.
You can just loop through the details items and specify what to show.

```
# Imports
from System.Drawing import Color
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

#Add a vis parameter referencing an existing LineChart visualization
vis = vis.As[BarChart]()

#Loop through all the Lines & Curves collection
Document.Properties['GenericVisualisationDescriptions'] = not Document.Properties['GenericVisualisationDescriptions']

for fm in vis.FittingModels:
    labels_tooltips=fm.Line.Details
    if Document.Properties['GenericVisualisationDescriptions']:
        for lt in labels_tooltips:
            lt.ShowInLabel=True    #turns label on
            lt.ShowInTooltip=True  #turns tooltip on
    else:
        for lt in labels_tooltips:
            lt.ShowInLabel=False   #turns label off
            lt.ShowInTooltip=False #turns tooltip off
```

In case you you want to just show/hide a specific element you can distinguish by them by the Name or DisplayName. Just print them to identify which elements you need:

`print lt.Name,lt.DisplayName,lt.ShowInLabel,lt.ShowInTooltip`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).